# Race condition in the Service(Android) (Too many threads)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, handler

I don't know why, but this function is going in the loop under Timer, user specifies how long he wants to wait in between the updates. Somehow the function halts (hangs) on the part, where "System.out.println("checking to add a new comment");". The interesting thing is that this code runs few times before the whole application freezes, so it doesn't have any errors

```
public ArrayList<String> newComments = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> downloadedComments = new ArrayList<String>();
```

---

```
 onStart(){
    if (receivedComments != null) {fthread
                for (int i = 0; i < receivedComments.size(); i++) {
                    if (newComments.contains(receivedComments.get(i))) {
                        System.out.println("Contains.");
                        newComments.remove(receivedComments.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

---

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        System.out.println("got msg");
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 1:
            int add = 0;
            System.out.println("start filling the comments");
            for (int i = 1; i < comments.size(); i++) {
                newComment = comments.get(i).text();
                // System.out.println(newComment);
                System.out.println("checking to add a new comment");
                if (!downloadedComments.contains(newComment)) {
                    newComments.add(newComment);
                    System.out.println("additing");
                    downloadedComments.add(newComment);
                    System.out.println("added");
                    add++;
                    // System.out.println("New comments");
                    // System.out.println(newComments);
                }
                // downloadedComments.add(newComment);
            }

            // System.out.println(add);

            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("time refresh");
            timeUpdate.scheduleAtFixedRate(new UpdateGui(context,
                    appWidgetManager), 1, 3000);
        }
    }
};
```

---

UpdateGUI class

```
private class UpdateGui extends TimerTask {
        Context context;

        public UpdateGui(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < newComments.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("sleeping");
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (newComments.size() > 0) {
                        notificationView.setViewVisibility(
                                R.id.widget_notificationtext,
                                LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                        notificationView.setTextViewText(
                                R.id.widget_notificationtext,
                                String.valueOf(newComments.size()));
                    } else {
                        notificationView.setViewVisibility(
                                R.id.widget_notificationtext,
                                LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    if (newComments.size() != 0) {
                        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text,
                                newComments.get(i));
                    } else {
                        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text,
                                "No unread comments");
                    }
                    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
                    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget,
                            notificationView);
                }
try {
                        System.out.println("sleeping");
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }

    }
```

Since I am waiting every time 3 seconds to update my GUI from the thread, i did not consider what to do when there is nothing to update it with, so the code is being executed at once, but now i added a three seconds delay there as well and everything works just fine. I know that this is not the best design of the application, but i could not come up with anything more eficient than this for now.
This was a typical race condition during the update when there is nothing to update, so a simple sleep would help

Comment: Which case is executed, case 2? What does UpdateGui look like?

Comment: it depends, every 3 seconds gui updates, so case 2, and every say 5 minutes case 1

Comment: I\ve been thinking that maybe .contains function is too slow, maybe it could be better to iterate through the elements

Comment: actually everything works very good, before the remove function is triggered.. after doing remove, and continuing with iteration and looking for the same elements, then execution halts

Comment: Is it hanging in the `for` loop? put a comment before `break;` of case 1.

Comment: did not help to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd bet a good amount that this is basically a race condition issue. You are using a bunch of different threads (UI, Timer, Handler, and possibly more). `ArrayList` is not a synchronized or thread safe class, which means that it's entirely possible that `downloadedComments` is getting updated while at the same time .contains() is running, causing the internal loop to run basically forever. If you are not passing the data to the various targets (thus ensuring that nothing is being modified in two places), you will have to wrap the accesses in `synchronized` blocks to prevent concurrent access.

Note that you can get a synchronized version of the list thus:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
```

Synchronization of every method has performance implications. That may not matter for you, though.

Comment: I've been thinking about that.. Is it better to get use of handler for almost every action on the set? I think it might be a problem..

Comment: It's likely a good solution to do so. If you use the same handler, then when it's time to query a message, for example, the handler can auto-post that message (using postDelayed, and the running function can repost the same message to repeat later). The advantage is that everything in the handler is in a single thread, so there's no chance of overlap. Note however that multiple handlers have separate threads based on where they were started, so it makes sense only if you use one single handler.

Comment: The thing is that when I run this code without actually updating GUI, then everything works just perfectly, but there is a separate thread that does updates to gui and it is all under switch statement and signals are send into the thread from different parts of the code notifying to change the GUI, so it should not be a problem of the ArrayLists being updated at nearly the same time during the runtime. I will take a closer look at it tomorrow

Comment: The execution become much better when I got rid of the handler and executed everything sequentially without Timers